# Function help in vb.net 2010 - finding the minimum value in a sequence of numbers separated by commas in one string

Tags: vb.net

I need to create a function that finds the minimum value of a sequence of numbers separated by commas. The whole sequence is input into only one textbox(textbox1). Could someone help me create function that uses a string search and then compares each number to eachother and outputs the smallest value?

Answer (score 3):

What you want can be done with a combination of the Split method and the Min method.  Something like this:

```
Dim MinInt As Double = Split(TextBox1.Text, ",").Min(Function(i) Double.Parse(i))
```

Of course this doesn't validate the text in the textbox.  But this will return the lowest numerical value in the string you describe.

Comment: Oh come on! This is clearly homework - why did you show him source code instead of a description? ;-)

Comment: At least this has no error handling!

Answer (score 2):

Since it looks like homework here are the building blocks:

1. use `string.split()` to seperate the values
2. parse each value into a `List<int>`
3. then use `LINQ .MIN()` to get the smallest value-.